# Laravel Sail emelisearch docker error Error: An internal error has occurred. `Permission denied (os error 13) (Mac OS Monterey m1)

Tags: php, laravel, macos, docker, macos-big-sur

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmMSO.png
I enter sail -d and the container with meilisearch crashes with an error Error: An internal error has occurred. Permission denied (OS error 13).

I need a misspelled search, tried soundex, the result doesn't match. Maybe someone knows how to do this with native means, or how on mac os m1, run the meilisearch container

docker-compose standard as when installing sail

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        platform: linux/x86_64
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        environment:
            MEILI_DB_PATH: '/data.ms'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEyPm.png)

DOCKERFILE

```
    FROM ubuntu:21.04
    
    LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"
    
    ARG WWWGROUP
    ARG NODE_VERSION=16
    
    WORKDIR /var/www/html
    
    ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
    ENV TZ=UTC
    
    RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
    
    RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
        && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
        && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
        && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
        && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
        && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
        && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
        && apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev \
           php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd \
           php8.1-curl \
           php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring \
           php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap \
           php8.1-intl php8.1-readline \
           php8.1-ldap \
           php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole \
           php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug \
        && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
        && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
        && apt-get install -y nodejs \
        && npm install -g npm \
        && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
        && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
        && apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y yarn \
        && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
        && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
        && apt-get -y autoremove \
        && apt-get clean \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
    
    RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.1
    
    RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
    RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail
    
    COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
    COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
    COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
    RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container
    
    EXPOSE 8000
    
    ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

Comment: Please add your docker-compose file. It makes it easier to fire up a test.

Comment: @Tschallacka  updated the question, added docker-compose

Comment: Have you made any changes to the sail installation? Can you share the Dockerfile?

Comment: @Tschallacka 
i made no changes, updated the question, added dockerfile